# Switch statement matching any of a set of cases

Tags: r, switch-statement

As an example, I have a `switch()` statement in R which checks whether a letter is a vowel or not, as follows:

```
switch(trial_code[i],
     'a' = {letter[i] <- 'vowel'
     },
     'e' = {letter[i] <- 'vowel'
     },
     'i' = {letter[i] <- 'vowel'
     },
     'o' = {letter[i] <- 'vowel'
     },
     'u' = {letter[i] <- 'vowel'
     },
     {letter[i] <- 'consonant'}
)
```

I would have thought there must be some way of checking multiple cases at the same time, to tidy my code. I have tried the following, with no luck:

```
switch(trial_code[i],
     'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' = {letter[i] <- 'vowel'
     },
     {letter[i] <- 'consonant'}
)
```

What is the correct syntax to check the `switch()` statement against any value in a list?

**EDIT**: I should point out that this is a MWE. I am trying to find a solution to the problem of using a switch statement against multiple possible matching cases; I am not trying to assign letters to vowels or consonants in my actual program.

Comment: Maybe just (untested) `c('consonant', 'vowel')[(letter %in% c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')) + 1]` ? (if `letter` is the vector that contains your letters which you want test)

Comment: what do you mean by MWE ? can you edit your question ?(as such, David and I answered your question)

Comment: Minimum working example

Comment: Thanks David; this would work as a workaround, but I'm actually looking for a solution for the problem of using multiple matching cases in a switch statement (my actual programming problem is very different to the MWE presented above)

Comment: What is your *real* problem then? You should create an example that actually reflects your problem. Are you sure you need `switch` for your *real* problem?

Comment: I could solve the problem in my code using ifelse statements, but I'm more interested in whether or not it is a actually possible to use a `switch` statement when there are multiple possible matches. This is more of a theoretical question

Comment: `iflese` is always a bad choice to solve a problem. I don't think what you are trying to do is possible and not sure is necessary.

Comment: I guess your MWE has not be formulated correctly!

Comment: Thanks David, that's useful to know. I just wanted to know if this was possible. 'No' is a valid answer!

Comment: I wouldn't establish as a fact based on me saying "I don't think [something] is possible"

Comment: Besides, you left out "Sometimes y"  .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The help page for [`switch`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/switch) describes how to do this.

> If `EXPR` evaluates to a character string then that string is matched (exactly) to the names of the elements in `...`. If there is a match then that element is evaluated unless it is missing, in which case the next non-missing element is evaluated ...

And then goes on to give an example which in your case would look like

```
switch(trial_code[i],
     'a' = ,
     'e' = ,
     'i' = ,
     'o' = ,
     'u' = {letter[i] <- 'vowel'},
     {letter[i] <- 'consonant'}
)
```

This may or may not be the best way to approach your problem, but this is how to specify multiple values to have the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason of using `switch` if all you do is the same operation over and over. You can use a simple indexing and `%in%` instead.

For example, lets say this is your letters vector

```
set.seed(123)
(letter <- sample(letters, 20))
# [1] "h" "t" "j" "u" "w" "a" "k" "q" "x" "z" "p" "g" "r" "s" "b" "n" "c" "v" "y" "o"
```

Then, simply do

```
c('consonant', 'vowel')[(letter %in% c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')) + 1]
#  [1] "consonant" "consonant" "consonant" "vowel"     "consonant" "vowel"     "consonant" "consonant"
#  [9] "consonant" "consonant" "consonant" "consonant" "consonant" "consonant" "consonant" "consonant"
# [17] "consonant" "consonant" "consonant" "vowel"
```

Comment: Thanks. The actual problem I'm trying to solve is not this one though. This is a MWE.

Comment: @CaptainProg  a **valid** MWE will demonstrate the behaviour you need.  Clearly you have not given us a useful sample.

Comment: @CaptainProg Then I guess you don't really have a MWE since it's not an example of what you actually want to do...